# Remove the blank space between a quote and character

Tags: vba, ms-word

My text: “ Pulp Speed. ”

I use the [A-Z] because it could contain any letter at the start.

My objective is to remove the space between the quote and first letter that starts the sentence.

My code is a find and replace:

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
    End With
    .Execute FindText:=ChrW(8220) & " ([\@A-Z])", Replacewith:="""\1", _
      Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
```

I am trying to remove the blank space between the Quote and the P.
I get P“ulp Speed.”

I have rearranged it and found that sometimes it works. It will place it one time in front and then the next time behind. More often it won't work.

Made the updates mentioned below but still get P"ulp Speed."

Answer (score 0):

You set the parameters wrong for the `find`-object

You have to set `MatchWildcards = true` to enable a wildcard/regex search.

Furthermore `.Wrap` is not a boolean value but takes eg. `wdFindContinue`

So your code should look like this:

```vb
With ActiveDocument.Range.Find

    .ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
    
    With .Replacement
        .ClearFormatting
    End With
    
    .Execute FindText:=ChrW(8220) & " ([\@A-Z])", Replacewith:="""" & "\1", _
    Format:=True, Replace:=wdReplaceAll

End With
```

Comment: In addition, `Format:=True` in the `.Execute` line is also incorrect, and unnecessary. `Format = False` is set correctly in the `With` block as the Find is not looking for formatting.

Comment: Didn't saw that - thanks.

Comment: So I made those changes and I am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: Hard to tell ...